# Show ProgressDialog after clicking on AlertDialog button

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have `AlertDialog` and I want to show `ProgressDialog` after clicking on `AlertDialog` positive button (during Internet connection - `AsyncTask`). Problem is that Progress dialog shows only after finishing task and when `AlertDialog` is closed. I tried to hide() or dismiss() `AlertDialog` but it doesnt work.

Any idea how to show ProgressDialog in front of AlertDialog? This is my code.

```
LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(kontekst);
final View vNearest;
vNearest  = li.inflate(R.layout.nearest, null);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(kontekst);
builder.setView(vNearest);
builder.setCancelable(true);

builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int witch) {

    String xml = "www.example.com";
    MarkerOptions nearestMO = new  DownloadXmlTask().execute(xml).get();
    String distance = nearestMO.getSnippet();

      }
    });
```

***DownloadXmlTask AsyncTask:***

```
private class DownloadXmlTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, MarkerOptions> {

ProgressDialog waitDialog;

@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    waitDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Home.this, "Working", "Please Wait", true, true);
    waitDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
}

@Override
protected MarkerOptions doInBackground(String... urls) {

    try{             
        URL xmlURL= new URL(urls[0]);           
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        HandlingXMLStuff readingXML = new HandlingXMLStuff();
        xr.setContentHandler(readingXML);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(xmlURL.openStream()));

        return readingXML.getNearest();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
  protected void onPostExecute(MarkerOptions result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
            waitDialog.dismiss();
}

}
```

Comment: tried dialog.cancel() inside onClick()

Comment: @Mitesh I've tried it doesnt work..

Comment: is this full code?? are you able to show alert dialog?

Comment: @Mitesh No, it's not full code, just important part. It shows alertdialog, problem is that it doesnt show ProgressDialog during task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove .get() from the asynctask call. In OnPostExecute use getSnippet().

Comment: Yeah, It seems that .get() was freezing AlertDialog. Thanks!